# Wireless 3 sensor 1 pi home project

Tags: sensor, wireless

I have little to no experience with setting up a wireless "network" for my raspberry pi and need help.
I want to set up 3 hygrometers in separate rooms which connect to the same one pi. I don't want the sensors to be connected to the pi via cables but preferably wireless. Yet, I never did this myself and have no Idea where to start/what existing techniques exist. Obviously, each hygrometer needs power supply and some sort of transmitter and the pi needs to have a receiving end which can deal with 3 different inputs simultaneously.

Is there an easy and preferably *cheap* way of doing this, or are there comparable threads with approaches available?
For your information: I have a raspberry pi 3 model B V1.2 and thought of the following [hydrometers](https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-AM2302-Temperatursensor-Luftfeuchtigkeitssensor-Arduino/dp/B074MZSZYF/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2Z1WC5640DCC2&keywords=dht22&qid=1640869564&sprefix=dht22%2Caps%2C78&sr=8-5&th=1).

Comment: Your question is about setting up a wireless data logging network. This is the same whatever you are proposing to collect the data, which could be any system.

Comment: Your project is a bit too big for newbies. Let us eat the big elephant by bytes, perhaps two big bites:  (1) The job is on wireless temperature and humidity sensors. You can break it into two independent parts: (a) sensor, (b) wireless network. We can make the first part first, and then expand it to wireless later.  (2) Your choice of DHT22 with Rpi3B+ is OK for newbies, and you can easily google references and instructables in this forum and DIY to get basic knowledge and skills. (3) DHT sensor is in turn in two parts: (i) temperature, (ii) humidity. I would suggest to start with temperature.